# Vaadin Grid: alternating row color if not using LUMO theme

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

For Grids using the LUMO theme there is an easy solution to get alternating row colors (look [here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples) under "Theme variants usage"). Furthermore if you know the number of grid columns you can set the colors using CSS selector `vaadin-grid-cell-content:nth-child(an+b)`. But unfortunately both of these conditions are not met in our case.

How can one achieve alternating row colors in general cases?

The only solution I can come up with is using List input data and defining a row class generator as follows:

```
grid.setClassNameGenerator(i -> (entities.indexOf(i) % 2) == 0 ? "even-row" : "");
```

But I would like to use all types of Collection as input data.

Comment: Have you tried mimicking what lumo does? `:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([odd]) [part~="body-cell"]`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I also searched for this behavior but could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, look at the comment from [cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick). The CSS selector is

```
:host([theme~="row-stripes"]) [part~="row"]:not([odd]) [part~="body-cell"]
```